# Running tor browser on raspberry pi 2

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to use tor browser on my raspberry pi 2. I've downloaded and extracted the tar.xz but I can't get the tor browser to open. I navigate to tor-browser_en-US in the LXTerminal and type:-

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop
```

This returns the message:-

```
Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach'...
```

But nothing happens. 
Am I making some basic mistake like I have to change a .config file somewhere? I'm totally new to tor and whilst I've found a lot of advice on setting up a tor relay using a raspberry pi I've had difficulty finding advice on browsing using tor browser on a raspberry pi. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPi{1,2,3} are ARM architecture SoCs, Tor Browser is currently only available for x86 (i386) or x86_64 (AMD64) on Linux, there is no Tor Browser for any ARM platforms.

As such you won't be able run Tor Browser natively on the RPi.

If you want to follow the progress or contribute to the porting of Tor Browser to ARM see [#12631](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12631) and similarly see [#10972](https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/10972) for work on porting [Tails](https://tails.boum.org) to ARM.

Comment: OK, I understand that I'm not going to be able to run tor browser through the RP but I'd like to understand more about the problem. My understanding is that x86 and x86_64 refer to the rate of data transfer from the RAM but what do the numbers actually refer to? How is ARM architecture different. I'm fairly new to linux and totally new to tor so I'm keen to learn more about the fields.

Comment: x86/x86_64 relate to the design and instruction set of the CPU. [See wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_instruction_set_architectures#Instruction_sets). You can run `tor` itself it can be built for ARM architectures but, but the browser won't build, it requires more work. I've added a link to my answer with more details on that.